# How to avoid problems where a new row is inserted in database accidentally?

Tags: sql-server

Did a good mistake today. And enterprise was down for 10 hrs. Microsoft sql server. Was editing a row via Views->Create a view. (I am a sysadmin not a db admin that's why).

Accidentally because of pressing enter, a new row was inserted with random values. Because of that the whole application stopped. This is such a weird thing for me.

Is there a way  I can prevent this in future. I don't want to update by using query, because that's even more risky. What worse? I had not taken the backup of table. Can you share ms-sql server query to take backup and also a query to rename a table?

Another big mistake of mine was that I forgot to tail the logs to check what was happening in application logs once I inserted a new row. Today I made an enterprise down and I feel so trash today.

Comment: "Is there a way I can prevent this in future" - if taking the enterprise down for 10 hrs is important (and it certainly sounds like it is) then you need to fix the process. e.g. changes to prod databases should not be done adhoc in the GUI but by a release pipeline that deploys the (scripted) change through test environment(s) first. So the fault is with the process that allows people to do this sort of change direct to prod with no testing. It is almost inevitable at some point this will cause a problem.

Comment: But.. with CREATE VIEW how you have inserted a new row?Anyway, you have a lot of methods to try to minimize impact... testing environment, pipeline, begin tran.... rollback tran in SSMS, impersonate a user with less grants with EXEC AS, database snapshot and be aware that you are in a production environment

Comment: @JeanNoel - It is possible. Though strange. "New view" opens the view designer.  Add a table to it and select the columns. Click the "Execute SQL" option and you get much the same editable grid as if you had selected the Edit option on the table in the first place

Comment: why is updating by a query more risky? it is far better for repeatability and consistency than poking around in flaky at best Management Studio WYSIWYG GUIs. As others have said, creating / following a safer process here is key

Comment: @SE1986 I mean what if I miss WHERE clause lol.

Comment: @achhainsan that should again be picked up by procedure - anything tested would hit this problem in a test environment. If no test environment is avaiable, getting into the habit of adding BEGIN TRAN at beggining of updates and manually committing when you are happy with the output should mitigate the no WHERE clause issue

Comment: @SE1986 Won't explicit transactions lock all the rows they touch? That sounds like unfortunate thing to do on production database.

Comment: @Yano of Queenscastle I don't believe the locking behaviour of what I am suggesting is any different to that of the default autocommit behaviour, the only difference is the user is controlling the start and end of the transaction including the giving the ability to rollback (useful if you are expecting 1 row to change and see that 1m have been affected). The longer you take to commit the transaction, the more processes may be blocked. Regardless it is better to test such a change ahead of time in a test env that is on a different server, a different DB on the same server or a copy of the table

Comment: "Won't explicit transactions lock all the rows they touch" the granularity of locking  depends on the query, indexes, isolation level, hints etc, the method of starting the transaction wouldn't change the locks taken.

Answer (score 3):

Write the necessary changes as SQL script, test it rigorously in testing environment and only then run them on production.

> What worse? I had not taken the backup of table. Can you share ms-sql server query to take backup and also a query to rename a table?

Backups in SQL Server is topic you could write books about. And sadly, you can't backup single table in SQL Server.
When I end up editing something on production, I usually "backup" the table by doing SELECT INTO.

```
SELECT *
INTO MyTable_Backup
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: There is no testing environment.

Comment: @achhainsan - this experience should be motivation to get one created then